# Tricky split string with regexpr

Tags: java, regex, split

I have this string

```
na23me=12341234las4tName=654567stree2t[696]=764545457OK
```

that I'd like to transform into this array:

```
['na23me=12341234', 'las4tName=654567', 'stree2t[696]=764545457', 'OK']
```

I thought this should have work:

```
String[] tokens = buffer.split("(?!^)(?=\\b\\w=\\d+)");
```

Comment: To clarify item1 should be `na23me=12341234` item2 should be 'last4tName=654567'

Comment: What is the max length of value (number after `=`)? In other words how many digits can appear there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex for splitting:

```
String str = "na23me=12341234las4tName=654567stree2t[696]=764545457OK";
String[] toks = str.split( "(?<==\\d{1,1000})(?=[a-zA-Z])" );
for (String tok: toks)
    System.out.printf("=> [%s]%n", tok);
```

**Output:**

```
=> [na23me=12341234]
=> [las4tName=654567]
=> [stree2t[696]=764545457]
=> [OK]
```

**Explanation:**

Regex uses a lookbehind and a lookahead for splitting:

- `(?<==\\d{1,1000})` is a positive lookbehind that makes sure current position is preceded by a `=` followed by 1 to 1000 digits
- `(?=[a-zA-Z])` is a positive lookahead that makes sure there is a letter following current position

Comment: I like the idea but `(?<=\\d{4})` should be probably replaced with something like `(?<==\\d{1,1000})` to search for values like `=123123`.

Comment: Actually I can use: `(?<=\\d{3,1000})` but anything less than 3 is the problem since there is `na23me` also in input.

Comment: But `23` has no `=` before it so this is no longer a problem (regex from my previous comment also requires `=` at start of the number).

Comment: could you explain the regex too?

Comment: @MihaiC: I added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!!

```
String pattern = "([^=]*=[\\d]*)([^=]*=[\\d]*)([^=]*=[\\d]*)(.*$)";
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(pattern );
    String string = "na23me=12341234las4tName=654567stree2t[696]=764545457OK";
    Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(string);
    if(matcher.matches()){
        int groupCount = matcher.groupCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < groupCount; i++) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(i+1));
        }
    }
```

Gets the output as follows:

```
na23me=12341234
las4tName=654567
stree2t[696]=764545457
OK
```

PS : `matcher.group(0)` will always be the full string. Hence use `i+1`

Comment: I like the solution ... what about if I'd like to consider this too?

String string = "na23me=12341234las4tName={{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}stree2t[696]=764545457OK";

like a more general string   token=value
?

Comment: is that a matrix?? list all the possiblities at once. You can get a better solution to the answer.

Here's the new Regex :
`([^=]*=[\\d\{,\\}]*){2}([^=]*=[\\d\\{,\\}]*)(.*$)`
PS : how can the last name be `matrix` :P